# resetting a script every time its called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use this script to set a timer for someone looting a player however i can't get it to reset after i call it a second time but it stores the original value of time left where as i want it to start fresh each time.
i am calling it from another script which enables and disables it on the OnTriggerEnter and OnTriggerExit methods

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Changetext : MonoBehaviour {
public float timeLeft = 5;
public Text countdownText;
public float cash = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void start()
{
    timeLeft = 5;
}

void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    countdownText.text = ("Time Left = " + timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        countdownText.text = "You got the cash";
        cash = 1;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Start() only gets called once in the gameobjects lifetime - so it won't toggle everytime you enable/disable.

You can instead use OnEnable() to reset the timer to 5;

```
void OnEnable()
{
   timeLeft = 5;
}
```

(as an FYI, Start() needs a capital 'S')

Comment: You should also consider disabling the script when the time runs out and and enabling the script when OnEnable is called so it Update method won't be called during that time